# The set of all complex homomorphisms of abelian group $G$ has the same structure as $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is an abelien group, let $\hat{G}$ be the set of all
>   homomorphisms of $G$ into the group of nonzero complex numbers under
>   multiplication. If $\phi_1, \phi_1\in \hat{G}$ define $\phi_1\cdot
>  \phi_2$ by $(\phi_1\cdot \phi_2)(g)=\phi_1(g)\phi_2(g)$ for all $g\in
>  G$.
>
> If $G$ is a finite abelian group prove that $o(G)=o(\hat{G})$ and $G$
>   is isomorphic to $\hat{G}$.

The case when $G$ is finite cyclic is easy because in this case $\hat{G} \cong G$. Let's consider the case when $G$ is abelian group of order $p^n$, $p$ - prime.

By Fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups we have the following: $$G=\langle a_1 \rangle_{p^{n_1}}\times \langle a_2 \rangle_{p^{n_2}} \times \dots \times \langle a_k \rangle_{p^{n_k}},$$

where $n_1\geq n_2\geq \dots \geq n_k>0$ and $n_1+\dots+n_k=n$.

Let $A_i=\langle a_i \rangle_{p^{n_i}}$ and $A_i$ are cyclic groups then $A_i\cong \hat{A_i}$. So we have the following $$G=A_1\times \dots \times A_k\cong \hat{A_1}\times \dots \times \hat{A_k}.$$

Then I was trying to think about $\hat{G}$ and I think that $\hat{G}=\hat{A_1}\times \dots \times \hat{A_k}$ which follows that $G\cong \hat{G}$.

How to prove rigorously that $\hat{G}=\hat{A_1}\times \dots \times \hat{A_k}$? I am not able to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if $\lambda, \beta:G\to K$ are two group homomorphisms with $K$ abelian then we define $\lambda+\beta:G\to K$ by $(\lambda+\beta)(x)=\lambda(x)+\beta(x)$. This is the pointiwise addition of homomorphisms and note that you need $K$ to be abelian in order for it to be a group addition defined on the set of all homomorphisms $\text{Hom}(G,K)$.

We also assume that the group operation on the Cartesian product $G\times H$ is pointwise as well.

---

Let $G,H,K$ be three groups with $K$ abelian and consider two homomorphisms:

$$j_G:G\to G\times H$$
$$j_G(g)=(g,1)$$
$$j_H:H\to G\times H$$
$$j_H(h)=(1,h)$$

Define

$$\Phi:\text{Hom}(G\times H, K)\to\text{Hom}(G, K)\times\text{Hom}(H, K)$$
$$\Phi(\lambda)=(\lambda\circ j_G, \lambda\circ j_H)$$

And treat each $\text{Hom}$ as a group via pointwise addition.

> **Lemma.** $\Phi$ is a group isomorphism.

**Proof.**

**1) $\Phi$ is a homomorphism:** Indeed,

$$\Phi(\lambda+\beta)=\big((\lambda+\beta)\circ j_G, (\lambda+\beta)\circ j_H\big)$$

Without the loss of generality lets consider the first coordinate only:

$$((\lambda+\beta)\circ j_G )(g)=(\lambda+\beta)(g, 1)=\lambda(g,1)+\beta(g,1)=\lambda\circ j_G(g)+\beta\circ j_G(g)$$

In other words

$$(\lambda+\beta)\circ j_G =\lambda\circ j_G+\beta\circ j_G$$

And analogously $(\lambda+\beta)\circ j_H=\lambda\circ j_H+\beta\circ j_H$ showing that

$$\Phi(\lambda + \beta)=\Phi(\lambda)+\Phi(\beta)$$

**2) $\Phi$ is invertible:** Indeed, consider the function

$$\Theta:\text{Hom}(G, K)\times\text{Hom}(H, K)\to\text{Hom}(G\times H, K)$$
$$\Theta(\lambda, \beta):G\times H\to K$$
$$\Theta(\lambda, \beta)(g,h)=\lambda(g)+\beta(h)$$

I leave as an exercise that $\Theta$ is the inverse of $\Phi$. $\Box$

Now that you have this result you can easily generalize it to any (finite) number of components by simple induction.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But let me ask you one question: you showed that $\Phi$ is homomorphism. But our goal to show that $\Phi$ is bijective homomorphism. Why you showed its invertibility instead of bijectivity?

Comment: @RFZ cause that's the same thing for group homomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It was an irrelevant question.

Comment: Let me ask you one more question: When I was proving that $\Theta$ is inverse to $\Phi$ I checked out that $\Phi \circ \Theta=\text{id}$ on $\text{Hom}(G; K)\times \text{Hom}(H; K)$. 

Let's prove that $\Theta\circ \Phi=\text{id}$ on $\text{Hom}(G\times H; K)$. If $\lambda \in \text{Hom}(G\times H; K)$ we need to prove that $\Theta\circ \Phi(\lambda)=\lambda$ then by definition of $\Phi$ we have: $\Theta(\lambda\circ i_G;\lambda\circ i_H)$ then taking any $(g,h)\in G\times H$ we have

Comment: $\Theta(\lambda\circ i_G;\lambda\circ i_H)(g,h)=(\lambda\circ i_G)(g)(\lambda\circ i_H)(h)=\lambda(g,1)\lambda(1,h)$. Why the last expression is equal to $\lambda(g,h)$? Would be grateful for explanation.

Comment: @RFZ Because $\lambda$ is a group homomorphism and group operation on $G\times H$ is pointwise.

Comment: yes indeed. Thanks for that nice answer since it helped me to solve the problem and understand the relation of these three objects. I accept you answer as the best :)