# Group homomorphism from finite abelian group to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, $g\in G$ be an element of order $n$ and  $\xi = \exp (\frac{2\pi i}{n})$.
I want to show that for each $0\leq i\leq n-1$, there are exactly $\frac{|G|}{n}$ group homomorphisms $G\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ which satisfy $g\mapsto \xi^i$.

I applied the structure theorem of finite abelian group, but it doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The set of all complex homomorphisms of abelian group $G$ has the same structure as $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757335/the-set-of-all-complex-homomorphisms-of-abelian-group-g-has-the-same-structure)

Comment: @M.Nestor No ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a finite abelian group we have $$|G|=|Hom(G,\Bbb{C}^*)|$$

Let $$f:Hom(G,\Bbb{C}^*)\to \mu_n, \qquad f(\chi)=\chi(g)$$ It is surjective so
$$Hom(G,\Bbb{C}^*)/\ker(f)\cong \mu_n$$
Whence any coset has size $$|Hom(G,\Bbb{C}^*)|/|\mu_n| = |G|/n$$